# How do I save the random generated string to a variable and compute the distance?

Tags: java, string, variables, random, distance

I am taking a Java class and was tasked to create a code with these parameters:

(Get String 1 –from user) Prompt the user to enter a string consisting of 5 uppercase characters and save this string in a variable.2.

(Get String 2 –randomly generated) Generate a string with 5 randomly generated characters and save it in a variable.

(Calculate Distance) Compute the distance between the two strings and display it to the user

I think I have cracked the first one and part of the second but am having trouble saving string2 to a variable and I can't seem to wrap my head around calculating distance.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class StringDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println ("Please enter 5 Capital letters.");
        int userString = scan.nextInt();
        
        Math.random().toString(255).substr(2, 5);           
    }
}
```

Comment: `int userString = scan.nextInt();` does _not_ read a string, you want `nextLine()` instead.

Comment: How do you define a *string distance*?

Comment: Thank You Thomas

Answer (score 0):

First: use nextLine(); insted of nextInt();

Second: To create a Random variable use this

1 import this class

```
        import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
```

2 create and initialize the variable

```
        int Random_number = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt("Here put the maximum number");
```

Comment: Thank you!  Does this work with letters as well? I need a random character.  Meaning letters and numbers I think.

Comment: Like this then?

Comment: int userString = scan.nextLine();

Comment: int randString = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5)

Comment: you can try try to create a random number and use a switch case for every letter, like 1 = a, 2 = b, 3 = c, 4 = d and you can try that width all letters of the alphabet.            or you can try with this                                  
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-random-string-of-given-size-in-java/